# Pass Today's date in the Endpoint URL

Tags: rest-api

I m trying to pass the Date variable value to the endpoint URL but it doesnt work. Not sure what I'm missing. When I try to give the date directly it works.

```
    Date fromdt = system.today()-1;
    Date toDt =system.today()-1;
    //String ep = 'https://api.etlhub.com/?from_date=fromdt&to_date=toDt'//When I pass the from date and to date from the date variable it doesnt work
    String ep = 'https://api.etlhub.com/?from_date=09-02-2021&to_date=09-07-2021'//When I provide the value it works.
    HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest();
    request.setMethod('GET');   
    request.setEndpoint(ep);
    request.setMethod(HTTP_method);       
    request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    request.setHeader('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key','xxx');
    request.setTimeout(120000);
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

`09-07-2021` (`MM-dd-yyyy`) isn't the standard for passing a Date, `yyyy-MM-dd` is.
You could take a look at [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) wiki page.

`String ep = 'https://api.etlhub.com/?companyId=77&from_date=fromdt&to_date=toDt'`
Here you are not converting the Date variable to a string representation, you're just creating a plain string. `toDt` and `fromdt` are only literal string there.
Anyway, even if you had concatenated a string to a date variable, the last one would have been translated to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.
`System.debug('hello ' + System.today());` will output `hello 2021-09-07 00:00:00`.

[Date](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_methods_system_date) class doesn't have a method to format a date using a custom formatter, but [Datetime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_formatGmt) does.
You can use `formatGmt(dateFormatString)` to get the string you need from a Datetime value.
So, instead of

```
Date fromdt = system.today()-1;
Date toDt =system.today()-1;
```

You should write

```
String fromdt = System.now().addDays(-1).formatGMT('MM-dd-yyyy');
String toDt = System.now().addDays(-1).formatGMT('MM-dd-yyyy');
String ep = 'https://api.etlhub.com/?companyId=77&from_date=' + fromdt + '&to_date=' + toDt
```

You can find more information about the `dateFormatString` parameter on [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Java docs.

Comment: Thank you. I did try that but it was exceeding the time limit. When I update the code like this - String fromdt = System.now().addDays(-1).formatGMT('MM-dd-yyyy');
            String toDt = System.now().addDays(-1).formatGMT('MM-dd-yyyy'); , it threw me an error - System.CalloutException: Exceeded maximum time allotted for callout (120000 ms)

Comment: @Kushitin it depends upon the other system, that takes more than two minutes to provide a response. You should get in touch with who developed that API in order to figure out the causes. By the way, the input parameter of `addDays()` (the `-1`) most likely should be dynamic, a variable, instead of an hardcoded value and probably `fromdt` and `toDt` should have different values, i.e. `-5` for `fromdt` and `-1` for `toDt`

Answer (score 0):

I havent encoded the From Date and ToDate. After doing that, it worked.